# cloning form with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am starting to learn jquery and wanted to figure out how to clone certain sections of a form. I have the following code and wanted to know why it only works when i click it once. If i click it more than once it doesn't do anything. what am i doing wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Intranet</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var clonedTable = $("#test").clone();

     $( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
        $("#mydiv").append(clonedTable);
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table id="test">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<a href="#">Clone</a>
<div id="mydiv">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

That is because the element is only created once (in the `document.ready`).
The same element is appended to the `#mydiv`.

If you want more clones do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        var clonedTable = $("#test").clone();
        $("#mydiv").append(clonedTable);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reuse...append a clone of the first clone, so original cached version stays in cached variable

```
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
    $("#mydiv").append(clonedTable.clone());
});
```

What is currently happening is you are inserting what was previously stored

Note that you will need to change ID every time to use as ID's must be unique

Answer (score 0):

here a working  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yB4GE/) define your cloned table at `click` function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        var clonedTable = $("#test").clone();
        $("#mydiv").append(clonedTable);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

---

### The Error

---

`var clonedTable` is created in `$(document).ready()`

---

### The Fix

---

As suggested by @putvande, if you create the `clonedTable` variable inside the `click` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        var clonedTable = $("#test").clone();
        $("#mydiv").append(clonedTable);
    });
});
```

then you will be creating a new clone of `$('#test')` *every time you click* and then appending it to `$("#mydiv")`.

**WARNING:**

Creating a clone carries over the ID so you can do one of three things:

1. Set the ID -- `$("#test").clone().attr('id', 'newID');`
2. Remove the ID -- `$("#test").clone().attr('id', '');`
3. Do not select the element by ID (eg: by class) -- `$(".selector").clone()`

---

### The Reason

---

Creating `clonedTable` inside of `$(document).ready()` will make a reference to the cloned element no matter what happens to it.

---